# MemoryLeak or not?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I experienced an OutOfMemory on my app and after some memory analyzing I got the following dominator tree. The first 4 instances are Activities that I started and directly closed. Since they hold a lot of views, the amount of memory that isn't garbage collected is huge.

[image: dominator tree]

If I then look into the path to GC for one of these elements I get the following:

[image: pathtogc]

The problem is that I don't know where these two references are coming from. I stripped the whole Activity to just have an onCreate/onDestroy, but I'm still getting these references. Does anybody know how to get rid of it so that the Activities can be garbage collected? Or is it a normal Android behavior and they will just disappear over time (which I doubt because I got the OutOfMemory)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you recycling the bitmaps properly in your app ?

Comment: ...and unbinding them?

Comment: The problem also occurs if I don't inflate any layout into the activity. So recycling bitmaps isn't an issue I suppose.

Comment: What do you mean by unbinding?